# Cayley transform of Kronecker sum

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, kronecker-product

Is there any relationship that simplifies the Cayley transform

$g(X) = \left(X - \mathrm{i}I_N\right)^{-1}\left(X + \mathrm{i}I_N\right)$,

where $X \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ and $I_N$ denotes the identity matrix, applied to the Kronecker sum

$X = A \oplus B = A \otimes I_M + I_M \otimes B$,

where $N = M^2$, $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product and $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$?

I guess that a decomposition in two matrices $C \otimes D$ is possible, but I cannot prove it. Additionally, the relationship may have certain constraints of course.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos I am fairly sure that X acts on $N=M^2$ due to the Kronecker products within the Kronecker sum.

Comment: The nicest property of the Cayley transform is that it's reversible
$$G=\left(\frac{X+iI}{X-iI}\right) \quad\iff\quad X=i\left(\frac{G+I}{G-I}\right)$$
while the nicest property of the Kronecker sum is
$$\exp(A)\otimes\exp(B) = \exp(A\oplus B) = \exp(X)$$
Therefore
$$\left(\frac{G+I}{G-I}\right) = -i\cdot\log\Big(\exp(A)\otimes\exp(B)\Big)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$g(X) = \left(X - \mathrm{i}I_N\right)^{-1}\left(X + \mathrm{i}I_N\right)\\= I_N  
  -2i \left(X - \mathrm{i}I_N\right)^{-1},$$
which invites you to examine the geometric series involved, i.e.,
arbitrary powers of *X*, all completely symmetrized in *A* and *B*; the cross terms, of course, do not vanish.

For example, 
$$
X^2= A^2\otimes I_M+I_M\otimes B^2+ 2 ~A\otimes B ,
$$
etc.

I strongly doubt you could recast the Cayley transform to a simple tensor product. Consider selective eigenvalues of the respective factors in the coproduct.

As per request, I don't have anything elegant. Consider *M*=2 , *A* and *B* both diagonalizable. So, without loss of generality, in their respective subspaces, they are *(a,b)* meaning diag$(a,b)$ and *(c,d)*, respectively: the diagonalizing similarity transformations in the subspaces tensor-factorize, so *X* is also diagonal, 
$$
X=(a+c, a+d,b+c,b+d).
$$
I have utilized the "right-factor matrix into each element of large 
left-factor matrix" convention for the tensor products.

Consequently,
$$
g(X)= \left (\frac{a+c +i}{ a+c -i},\frac{a+d +i}{ a+d -i},\frac{b+c +i}{ b+c -i},   \frac{b+d +i}{ b+d -i}\right ),
$$
which does not look like a simple function of *A* and *B*. To be sure, as per above, only powers of the denominator matter, and maybe there are Newton identities to the rescue, but there is no compact answer I can see.

Comment: The power series approach is an interesting approach, but indeed it seems that I cannot make any factorization. My initial guess is that a factorization is only possible for certain eigenvalues. Your last comment sounds promising, however, I am afraid I don't follow. Could you please elaborate on selective eigenvalues and the coproduct?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149380/cayley-transform-and-eigenvalues).